# C# WPF Buttons which have same event but they have different Tag as output

Tags: c#, wpf

Hello I have a question. I need to know how i can put one event for many buttons. Where every button will make ***labelfloor*** different text value(1-4 fro example)

```
   using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interakční logika pro MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            bool Aktive;
            bool lights;
            int actualyfloor;
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            labelFloor.Content = button(1-4).Tag.ToString(); // When i click at 1-4 button its will change value in labelFloor to (1-4)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button that was clicked should be given to you in the parameter `sender`.  Check that it is of type `Button` and then read the `Tag` property from it.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button button = sender as Button;
    if (button == null) return;

    labelFloor.Content = button.Tag.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks you , that helped me!

Comment: Glad to help.  If you could accept the answer when you're allowed that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Yes i will in 3 minutes. :)

Comment: Now it is accepted!